# How to inject views into TabControl using Prism?

Tags: wpf, prism

I followed from the quick start example about UICompositon. In my case I had a project A to hold the TabControl, a project B to hold the DataGrid which act as Content to be injected into the TabControl.

The TabControl has no viewModels, It uses

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="HeaderStyleS">
        <Setter Property="Header"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                Path=Content.DataContext.ViewName}" />
</Style>
<TabControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="TabRegion" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyleS}"></TabControl>
```

Project A is only responsible to inject itself into the main shell which is defined in project C;

```
regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MiddleRegion", () => container.Resolve<MainTabWindow>());
```

Project B is only responsible to inject itself into region `TabRegion`, which is defined in A.

```
regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TabRegion", () => container.Resolve<MetroDataGrid>());
```

Now The problem is the view-`B's Datagrid` is not shown on the Gui. The only part works is the `ViewName`,it verifies `Content.Datatext` is used correctly.But why the `Content DataGrid` is not shown?

[image]

Comment: Adding PRISM Regions in TabControl can be done using RegionAdaptors concept in PRISM.

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian Actually what happens is the default state of the Selected Tabitem is set to none. So After click, It shows it needs to show. I can't believe I'm stuck for 2 hours.